# jQuery dropdown menus when window<=768px

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two menus which have to disappear when screen width is equal or lower than 768px. When click on certain buttons they have to show up like dropdowns. 
Here is my problem - sometimes when I resize the browser <=768px more than 2 times, these functions could stop working, but if I continue resizing the browser buttons have a chance to work again. Here is my code:

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $(window).resize(function() {

      if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
        $('.categories-heading').click(function(){
          $('#menu-categories').toggle();
        });
        $('.navbar-toggle').click(function(){
          $('#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1').toggle();
        });
      }
      else if($(window).width() > 768) { 
        $('#menu-categories').css('display','block');
        $('#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1').css('display','block');
      }
    
    });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: try the .on() handler

Comment: You are re adding the `.click` binding every time you resize to `<= 768`, thus you are multiply bound and are getting weird results.  I'd rework this to put the check inside the `.click` event, or use bootstrap to only show those buttons on `-sm` classes.

Comment: remember to call Your $(window).width() rules also on document ready since the rules wont apply without the resize event (so wont apply in normal- non test scenario when some1 visits Your site from mobile device)

Answer (score 0):

Try the `.on()` handler for this kind of situations. Documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $(window).on("resize", function() {

  if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
    $('.categories-heading').click(function(){
        $('#menu-categories').toggle();
    });
    $('.navbar-toggle').click(function(){
      $('#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1').toggle();
    });
  }
  else if($(window).width() > 768) { 
    $('#menu-categories').css('display','block');
    $('#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1').css('display','block');
  }

});
});
```